# Yellow border around weapons, does it mean "fully upgraded"?

Tags: destiny

Some of my items has a yellow border instead of a white one.

It seems to me that this coincides with items where I have gotten all the upgrade slots. Specifically I see that an item where I have opened up all the upgrade slots, but not yet used them, is still white.

Can someone verify that this is what it means, yellow = fully upgraded, or if it means something else, what it means then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct. The Yellow border is used to denote an item that is fully upgraded. Your subclass will also get a yellow border when you have unlocked all the abilities for it.